# Return 2 rows at a time from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

How can I slice up my table and return and evenly distribute the data?

Because I wanted to slice this up and put it into my 3 combo boxes in a windows form.

Example :

### Table1

```
  ID          Name
   1           a
   2           b
   3           c
   4           d
   5           e
```

### Windows Form Output :

```
combobox1   combobox2  combobox3
  a             c          e
  b             d
```

Comment: You may apply PIVOT using ROW_NUMBER()%2 as a category. But I recommend to format the recordset on the client side.

Comment: This is called [pivoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017), but the output looks a bit weird. Do you need six column output? Is the division based on odd/even IDs? Please edit the question and add more details. Some sensible sample data might illustrate the use case better.

Comment: sorry i explain it wrong and ask for database output. 
what i wanted to really do is get 2 row and put it inside a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

This code should achieve what you want

```
SELECT [1] AS [Combobox1], [2] AS [Combobox2], [3] AS [Combobox3]
FROM
(
    SELECT [name],
        NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [CB]
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE [ID]%2 <> 0
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Name]) FOR [CB] IN ([1], [2], [3])
) pvt
UNION
SELECT [1] AS [Combobox1], [2] AS [Combobox2], [3] AS [Combobox3]
FROM
(
    SELECT [name],
        NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [CB]
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE [ID]%2 = 0
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Name]) FOR [CB] IN ([1], [2], [3])
) pvt
```

Sample output:

```
Combobox1 Combobox2 Combobox3
--------- --------- ---------
a         c         e
b         d         NULL
```